# Can't get Google USB driver to load

Tags: android

After getting my app to work in the emulator, I now want to test it on my Samsung Exhibit II Android phone.  I follow the instructions from google here http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html but can't get their USB driver to load.

When I plug the phone into the computer via the supplied USB data cable, Vista auto installs it's own driver and doesn't give me a chance to point to the google driver located here: `C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\android_winusb.inf`.

When I go to the device manager and right-click on the Vista driver and try to Update Driver Software to point to the Google driver, it says it already has the best one and won't change it! (even though it doesn't work, ie. no drive label appears for the phone plus the device manager shows an ! for it)

I've spent many hours reading dozens of posts with similar problems but no solutions work for me.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install Samsung Kies software to get the required drivers.
You can download it from this [Link](http://www.samsung.com/in/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/JSP).
Google USB driver will not be useful for Samsung mobiles.

**EDIT**: updated the link above.

Comment: Worked like a charm!  It automatically installed 4 drivers.  I compiled my app in eclipse and voila, there it was on the device.  Thank you Karthik!

Answer (score 0):

I think its because samsung is using its own usb driver. you should go to samsung's [website](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads) and search for your mobile phone model (or just google with the model name +usb driver) and use that should do the job

Comment: and also, you mentioned the auto install so I guess it is already included. in that case you may not need to do anything.. just auto install and whatever you wanted to do without the install usb driver step.

Comment: Yes, the device has it's own drivers.  When I follow device instructions for connecting to PC, I am able to see the device from the PC.  But I want to put my app on the device.  How to do that?  Google says I will get a device target chooser menu when I compile it in eclipse but I don't get that with device's drivers.  From the C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools if I enter "adb devices", it doesn't list my device.

Comment: after you install the drivers, you need to enable USB debugging option in settings. In device, Settings -> Applications -> Development -> Enable USB Debugging. Then connect your device to PC. You should be able to see the device in adb devices and also in Eclipse.

Comment: Yes, I had tried that.  Then it asks for 3 drivers, "CDC Abstract Control Model (ACM)", "CDC ACM Data", and "SAMSUNG_Android".  I am able to browse to the usb_driver folder created by the SDK Manager but get "Windows could not find driver software for your device" error for each driver.  Oh, now I understand your other comment.  Will try that next.